# Multiple navbars, both collapse buttons work, only one shows up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have two navbars, the first one is inverted and the other one is the default. Both make use of the collapse button feature and work properly, but the one from the default navbar doesn't show. I mean, it's there, but it's kind of invisible: Here's my code:

```
<div class="container main-container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse navigation" role="navigation">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".top-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse top-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


...


<nav class="navbar navigation" role="navigation">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".main-nav">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

My guess is that the second toggle button is somehow picking the style from the fisrt one and doesn't "realize" it should be rendered using the default colors. How would I go about solving this? Here's a [fiddle showing the behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/n6VGe/1/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `navbar-default` class in your second navbar, also you should use a `navbar-header` container for the toggle button.

See this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/KY2Pr/)** with the updated markup

Comment: I know I shouldn't reply with just a "thanks", but I still don't have enough rep to upvote you, so thank you, your solution worked perfectly. I don't know what's wrong with me!

Comment: @Cornholio no problem, you can however mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark below the voting arrows ;) ... after the 15 mins have passed

Comment: Yeah I was just waiting for the time out :)